# I want cummulative row for a given input

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below

```
Months   cnt
Jan        2
Feb        3
Mar        5
```

I want output like below

```
Months   cnt
Jan        2
Feb        2
Feb        3
Mar        2
Mar        3
Mar        5
```

I tried using below query but not getting the required output

```
Select distinct months, cnt, level 
from (select months, cnt, rownum row_cnt 
      from tablename) 
connect by level <= row_cnt
Order by months, cnt, level
```

Comment: Are these actually the abbreviations of the months stored as a varchar or is there a proper date or numeric month column to order by?

Comment: I have just named the column, instead of months you can use column name as col1 and values as a,b,c instead of jan,feb,mar

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option which *converts* month's names into their ordinal number (1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, etc.) and then - using self join - returns the result.

```
SQL> with test (months, cnt) as
  2    (select 'jan', 2 from dual union all
  3     select 'feb', 3 from dual union all
  4     select 'mar', 5 from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    (select
  8       months,
  9       to_number(to_char(to_date(months, 'mon', 'nls_date_language=english'), 'mm')) mon,
 10       cnt
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  select a.months, b.cnt
 14  from temp a join temp b on a.mon >= b.mon
 15  order by a.mon, b.cnt;

MON        CNT
--- ----------
jan          2
feb          2
feb          3
mar          2
mar          3
mar          5

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a self join:

```
select t.months, tt.cnt
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on extract(month from to_date(t.Months,'MON')) >= extract(month from to_date(tt.Months,'MON'))
order by extract(month from to_date(t.Months,'MON')), tt.cnt
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=93c2a325da2ecbb1a02fd22e6c0897fc).
Results:

```
> MONTHS | CNT
> :----- | --:
> Jan    |   2
> Feb    |   2
> Feb    |   3
> Mar    |   2
> Mar    |   3
> Mar    |   5
```